# How to Change Play/Pause audio icon within a ListView using RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, audio, android-recyclerview

so I want to change play icon with pause icon when the associated list item is clicked while the audio is playing and replace it again with play icon when its done .
here is my code for main activity :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
/** Handles playback of all the sound files */
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

/** Handles audio focus when playing a sound file */
private AudioManager mAudioManager;

/**
 * This listener gets triggered whenever the audio focus changes
 * (i.e., we gain or lose audio focus because of another app or device).
 */
private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener mOnAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT ||
                focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) {
            // The AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT case means that we've lost audio focus for a
            // short amount of time. The AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK case means that
            // our app is allowed to continue playing sound but at a lower volume. We'll treat
            // both cases the same way because our app is playing short sound files.

            // Pause playback and reset player to the start of the file. That way, we can
            // play the word from the beginning when we resume playback.
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
            // The AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN case means we have regained focus and can resume playback.
            mMediaPlayer.start();


        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
            // The AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS case means we've lost audio focus and
            // Stop playback and clean up resources
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    }
};

/**
 * This listener gets triggered when the {@link MediaPlayer} has completed
 * playing the audio file.
 */
private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // Now that the sound file has finished playing, release the media player resources.
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        ImageView im =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word_list);

    // Create and setup the {@link AudioManager} to request audio focus
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    // Create a list of words
    final ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
    words.add(new Word("one", "un", R.drawable.number_one, R.raw.number_one));
    words.add(new Word("two", "deux", R.drawable.number_two, R.raw.number_two));...........

    // Create an {@link WordAdapter}, whose data source is a list of {@link Word}s. The
    // adapter knows how to create list items for each item in the list.
    WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, words);

    // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
    // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
    // word_list.xml layout file.
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link WordAdapter} we created above, so that the
    // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Word} in the list.
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    // Set a click listener to play the audio when the list item is clicked on
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // Release the media player if it currently exists because we are about to
            // play a different sound file
            releaseMediaPlayer();

            // Get the {@link Word} object at the given position the user clicked on
            Word word = words.get(position);

            // Request audio focus so in order to play the audio file. The app needs to play a
            // short audio file, so we will request audio focus with a short amount of time
            // with AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT.
            int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener,
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                // We have audio focus now.

                // Create and setup the {@link MediaPlayer} for the audio resource associated
                // with the current word
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, word.getAudioResourceId());

                // Start the audio file
                mMediaPlayer.start();

                ImageView im =(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);


                // Setup a listener on the media player, so that we can stop and release the
                // media player once the sound has finished playing.
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // When the activity is stopped, release the media player resources because we won't
    // be playing any more sounds.
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}

/**
 * Clean up the media player by releasing its resources.
 */
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    // If the media player is not null, then it may be currently playing a sound.
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        // Regardless of the current state of the media player, release its resources
        // because we no longer need it.
        mMediaPlayer.release();

        // Set the media player back to null. For our code, we've decided that
        // setting the media player to null is an easy way to tell that the media player
        // is not configured to play an audio file at the moment.
        mMediaPlayer = null;

        // Regardless of whether or not we were granted audio focus, abandon it. This also
        // unregisters the AudioFocusChangeListener so we don't get anymore callbacks.
        mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
    }
}
```

}

and this is the code for the customized adaptor :

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word>  {


private int mColorResourceId;


public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
    super(context, 0, words);

}
```

private RelativeLayout rl ;

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }



        Random rnd = new Random();

        int[] colors = new int[2];
        colors[0] = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
        colors[1] = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));


    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
            new int[] {colors[0],colors[1]});
    gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(20f);

    rl = (RelativeLayout) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.rel);
    rl.setBackground(gradientDrawable);



    Word currentWord = getItem(position);


    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID miwok_text_view.
    TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);
    // Get the Miwok translation from the currentWord object and set this text on
    // the Miwok TextView.
    miwokTextView.setText(currentWord.getMiwokTranslation());



    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID default_text_view.
    TextView defaultTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);
    // Get the default translation from the currentWord object and set this text on
    // the default TextView.
    defaultTextView.setText(currentWord.getDefaultTranslation());



    // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews) so that it can be shown in
    // the ListView.
    return listItemView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need to add a property to your Word object. 
I suggest to add a **boolean variable *"isPlaying"*** and change its value on click and also in your completion listener. The play/pause icon source should be resolved in onBindViewHolder.
To apply changes a simple **notifyDatasetChanged()** after the change of the value should do the trick.
Hope it was at least somehow useful

Comment: thanks bro but Im just a beginner and honestly I don't know where to apply these changes